# Spark Streaming subscribe multiple topics and write into multiple topics

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have some kafkas topics with the nomenclatures below:

```
'ingestion_src_api_iq_BTCUSD_1_json', 'ingestion_src_api_iq_BTCUSD_5_json', 'ingestion_src_api_iq_BTCUSD_60_json'
```

I'm reading all these topics that has the same data structure using the `"subscribePattern"` param in spark.

```
 (spark.readStream.format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrap_server)
    .option("subscribePattern", "ingestion_src_api.*")
    .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
    .load()
    .select(col("topic").cast("string"), from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias("value")) 
.   select(to_json(struct(expr("value.active_id as active_id"), expr("value.size as timeframe"),
    expr("cast(value.at / 1000000000 as timestamp) as executed_at"), expr("FROM_UNIXTIME(value.from) as candle_from"), 
    expr("FROM_UNIXTIME(value.to) as candle_to"), expr("value.id as period"), 
    "value.open", "value.close", "value.min", "value.max", "value.ask", "value.bid", "value.volume")).alias("value"))
    .writeStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrap_server)
    .option("topic", "processed_src_api_iq_data")
    .option("checkpointLocation", f"./checkpoint/")
    .start()   
    )
```

How could I write the transformed data into differents topics like:

```
'processed_src_api_iq_BTCUSD_1_json', 'processed_src_api_iq_BTCUSD_5_json', 'processed_src_api_iq_BTCUSD_60_json'
```

In my code I am able to write only in one topic `"processed_src_api_iq_data"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outgoing dataframe to `format("kafka")` can include a String column named `topic` which will determine where the `value` and/or `key` byte/string columns will be produced to, rather than using `option`, as documented...

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#writing-data-to-kafka

> The `topic` column is required if the `“topic”` configuration option is not specified

Use `withColumn` to add the necessary values, based on the other columns that you have.

---

Alternatively, create multiple dataframes and call `writeStream.format("kafka")` with the invidiual `option("topic"` settings on each.

```
raw_df = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrap_server)
    .option("subscribePattern", "ingestion_src_api.*")
    .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
    .load()

parsed_df = raw_df.select(col("topic").cast("string"), from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias("value")) 

processed_df = parsed_df
    .select(to_json(struct(
        expr("value.active_id as active_id"), 
        expr("value.size as timeframe"),
        expr("cast(value.at / 1000000000 as timestamp) as executed_at"), 
        expr("FROM_UNIXTIME(value.from) as candle_from"), 
        expr("FROM_UNIXTIME(value.to) as candle_to"), 
        expr("value.id as period"), 
        "value.open", "value.close", "value.min", "value.max", "value.ask", "value.bid", "value.volume"
    )).alias("value"))

btc_1 = processed_df.filter( ... something to get just this data )
btc_5 = processed_df.filter( ... etc )

btc_1.writeStream.format("kafka")
   .option("topic", "processed_src_api_iq_BTCUSD_1_json")
   ...
btc_5.writeStream.format("kafka")
   .option("topic", "processed_src_api_iq_BTCUSD_5_json")
   ...
```